# Node.js Connection failing on connecting to RabbitMQ

Tags: mysql, node.js, rabbitmq

I have a node.js app to be running with rabbitmq and mysql.
After setting everything up, when I do `npm start`

I have given the user administrator tag and permissions as 
rabbitmqctl set_permissions RABBIT_USERNAME ".*" ".*" ".*"

It shows this error :

```
> node app.js

13:43   
Started database log (Mon Jan 29 2018 13:43:42 GMT+0530 (IST))
13:43   
Started mailer log (Mon Jan 29 2018 13:43:44 GMT+0530 (IST))
13:43   
Started messaging log (Mon Jan 29 2018 13:43:44 GMT+0530 (IST))
13:43   
Started messaging log (Mon Jan 29 2018 13:43:44 GMT+0530 (IST))
13:43   
Started database log (Mon Jan 29 2018 13:43:44 GMT+0530 (IST))
13:43   
Started socket log (Mon Jan 29 2018 13:43:44 GMT+0530 (IST))
13:43   messaging:3000 is listening..
13:43   DB connected (7)
13:43   DB connected (6)
13:43   Error:



 Expected ConnectionOpenOk; got <ConnectionClose channel:0>
 Error: Expected ConnectionOpenOk; got <ConnectionClose channel:0>
    at /PATH/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:167:14
    at /PATH/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:159:12
    at Socket.recv (/PATH/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:497:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:255:19)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:520:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:514:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:280:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:599:20)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! messaging@ start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the messaging@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mishal23/.npm/_logs/2018-01-29T08_13_45_095Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ? What version of Node? Do you see errors in the RabbitMQ logs? Have you worked through [the tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html)? Please provide your code (or at least the part that connects to RabbitMQ). I'm sure there is a simple fix involved.

Answer (score 15):

There is no enough context on how this happened so I'm making a few assumptions:

1. RabbitMQ is not installed locally and it is installed on some server.
2. You're using [`amqplib`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) for the connection. (*Not an assumption*)
3. You haven't created any Virtual Hosts.

---

## Setting Up

So the first thing you need to do is to create a user if you haven't already.

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user admin password
sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator
```

Run this command if you haven't enabled the Management Dashboard

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

By default, it runs on port `15672`. So don't forget to open that port. And you can access this dashboard using `your.server.ip.address:15672`.

Now in this Management Dashboard, go to the `Admin` tab and on the right side, you'll see a link to `Virtual Hosts`.

There will be one virtual host named `/` and user `guest` (that you cannot access without localhost). Now create a new virtual host and check if it has the same user as you just created a few moments back (`admin` in this case).

## Connecting to the RabbitMQ server

Use the string below to connect to the server instead of `amqp://localhost`

```
amqp://admin:password@your.server.ip.address/vhost_name
```

You can use [this example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html) (or any other examples) for the rest of the things...

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Go to the rabbitmq dashboard > click admin menu > select your user from which you want to connect > click set permission button > restart server

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was related to heartbeat. You have to pass the heartbeat as a parameter to your connection URL:

```
amqps://user:password@domain/vhost_name?heartbeat=30
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so bizarre, but it worked for me too. Glad I found your answer!